# Changing values and Concatenating into readable Dates

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 columns called MONTH, and YEAR.

The YEAR is just pulling in as INT and contains values such as

- 2017
- 2018
- 2019

etc...

The MONTH column however is pulling in as:

- 01-JAN
- 02-FEB
- 03-MAR
- 04-APR
- 05-MAY

etc...

I need a readable date out of this, ideally your typical short date:

- 01/01/2019
- 02/01/2019
- 06/01/2019

I am unfamiliar with CASE functions (actually I'm just unfamiliar with getting them to work without errors)

```
SELECT
MONTH as "Month",
YEAR as "Year",
CASE
WHEN MONTH = "01-JAN" THEN "01/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "02-FEB" THEN "02/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "03-MAR" THEN "03/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "04-APR" THEN "04/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "05-MAY" THEN "05/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "06-JUN" THEN "06/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "07-JUL" THEN "07/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "08-AUG" THEN "08/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "09-SEP" THEN "09/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "10-OCT" THEN "10/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "11-NOV" THEN "11/01/"
WHEN MONTH = "12-DEC" THEN "12/01/"
END as MONTH_TEXT
FROM
ABCDE.HIJ_KLM_NOP_QRS_VW
```

I am assuming two different things will be occurring here... changing the MONTH column from its current form (i.e. 01-JAN) to a readable MONTH/DAY format that would look something like 01/01/

Then concatenating that with YEAR

```
CONCATENATE(MONTH_TEXT,YEAR)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which rdbms it is ?

Comment: where do you have the date value ?

Comment: Everything is being pulled from Oracle DBs... using Tableau to pull the custom SQLs, but they don't understand a lot of the advanced SQL

Comment: @StevieG Please check answer added by me.

Comment: this is  a horrible data model. Why don't you store everything in a single column of type `DATE`

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
with dataa as
(SELECT '2019' AS YEAR, '01-JAN' AS MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2019' AS YEAR, '02-FEB' AS MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2019' AS YEAR, '03-MAR' AS MONTH FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '2018' AS YEAR, '30-DEC' AS MONTH FROM DUAL
)
SELECT
    TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_DATE(MONTH
                          || '-'
                          || YEAR, 'DD-MON-YYYY'), 'MONTH'), 'MM/DD/YYYY') 
    AS YOUR_OUTPUT
FROM
    DATAA
```

[DB Fiddle Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=3aae978eb57462c683ac2fd5b97a963f)

**Output:**

[image]

I have truncated(as per my understanding from the question) the date to start of the month. If you do not want this then you can remove `trunc(....,'month')` from the above code.

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use LEFT to grab the month, and use MAKEDATE to output as a Date:

```
Select MAKEDATE(YEAR, substr(Month,1,2),'01') from mytable
```

Comment: That is non-standard SQL, please mention the DBMS product where this works.

Comment: It is worth noting that Tableau is what I'm using to pull in this data, and from what I understand thus far, it's not intuitive at all...  Here is the error I get using your code:

"Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "DATEFROMPARTS": invalid identifier"

Comment: everything is pulled from Oracle DBs, and the software I'm using to pull these queries is Tableau which is not at all good at this:  I've had to keep much of my queries as basic as possible:  Simple... pull this column, LEFT, UPPER, etc... no arrays of any kind work

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, that's standard T-SQL. The OP had not specified an RDBMS when they posted. Oracle has the same function but it is called MAKEDATE

Comment: "Standard T-SQL" is something different than "standard SQL" (Microsoft does **not** define the SQL standard) As long as no DBMS is mentioned in the question, you shouldn't post DBMS specific solutions - or at least mention for which product your code works.And no, Oracle [does not](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/Functions.html#GUID-D079EFD3-C683-441F-977E-2C9503089982) have a function `makedate()`

Comment: yep beg pardon-  i was looking at Oracle DML

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it will give first two characters of your month column, then add /01/ and then the year.

```
SELECT (SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 2) + "/01/" + YEAR) as ShortDate FROM ABCDE.HIJ_KLM_NOP_QRS_VW
```

Comment: Here's the code that will not work:

    SELECT
MONTH as "Month",
YEAR as "Year",
FACILITY_ID as "Facility ID (lookup)",
EMP_COUNT as "Employee Count",
TOTAL_IDEAS as "Total Ideas",
IDEAS_CLOSED as "Ideas Closed",
IDEAS_OPEN as "Ideas Open",
VS_ID as "VS ID (lookup)",
MFG_ID as "MFG ID (lookup)",
CIP_SOURCE_COUNT as "CIP Source Count",
(SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 2) + "/01/ + YEAR) as "ShortDate"
FROM
TTTCIP.CIP_MFG_EMP_DESC_VW
WHERE
(FACILITY_ID='R8')

Sorry I have no idea how to input code correctly into this site

Comment: Is there an error? Or what is the output look like?

Comment: Your missing a second " on the + "/01/"

Comment: Oracle Database error 904: ora-00904: "/01/": invalid identifier

Comment: Ah, oracle try this instead (SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 2) || "/01/" || YEAR) as "ShortDate"

Comment: I'm pulling this data in using Tableau's Custom SQL feature...and it's not intuitive... the language has to be as basic as it gets... it does not understand anything complicated... however, your code seems pretty straightforward... so I'm not sure what's happening

Comment: Same exact error:

SELECT
(SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 2) || "/01/" || YEAR) as "ShortDate"
FROM
ABCDE.FGHI_JKL

Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "/01/": invalid identifier

Comment: oh oracle is single quotes try SELECT (SUBSTRING(MONTH, 1, 2) || '/01/' || YEAR) as "ShortDate" FROM ABCDE.FGHI_JKL

Comment: ugh.
Oracle database error 904: ORA-00904: "SUBSTRING": invalid identifier

Comment: haha, gotta love syntex try (SUBSTR(MONTH, 1, 2) || '/01/' || YEAR) as "ShortDate" FROM ABCDE.FGHI_JKL

Comment: yes! yes! yes!    UGH!  That was so painful.  Date came out perfectly.  Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear it!

Comment: Okay... so it comes out as text... how to do tell SQL to make this column a date column?

Comment: CAST( (SUBSTR(MONTH, 1, 2) || '/01/' || YEAR) AS DATE) AS "ShortDate"

Comment: So I've attempted to use CAST in the past with Tableau and I'm fairly certain you cannot... But I do believe that TO_DATE will work.  However, I'm running into an annoying error I see pretty often:     
TO_DATE(SUBSTR(MONTH, 1, 2) || '/01/' || YEAR) AS "ShortDate"
      
Oracle database error 907: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: TO_DATE((SUBSTR(MONTH, 1, 2) || '/01/' || YEAR),'MM/DD/YYYY') AS "ShortDate"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:-

```
SELECT concat(
            CASE WHEN MONTH = "01-JAN" THEN "01/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "02-FEB" THEN "02/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "03-MAR" THEN "03/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "04-APR" THEN "04/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "05-MAY" THEN "05/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "06-JUN" THEN "06/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "07-JUL" THEN "07/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "08-AUG" THEN "08/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "09-SEP" THEN "09/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "10-OCT" THEN "10/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "11-NOV" THEN "11/01/" 
            WHEN MONTH = "12-DEC" THEN "12/01/" END, '/', Year
       ) as Added_date 
FROM table
```

Output is :

[image]

Comment: @Stevie G Please accept the answer if it work for you